# Dynamic drag and drop jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-ui-sortable, drag, droppable

I'm trying to create dynamic droppable containers so I can move a sorted list between them.

I have a sorted list with orders in and a multi select drop down ( http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/) which is populated from code behind

Each time an item is selected I want to dynamically add a droppable div which I can populate by dragging and dropping from the sorted list to any of the containers into a sortable list in that div, between the containers or back to the sorted list.

I can create the droppable containers, but I can't get the items from the sorted list to drop into them.

Below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").multiselect({
            click: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.checked) {
                    addGroup(ui.value)
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addGroup(container) {
        var x = $("<div class='dropcontainer' id='" + container + "'><p>GROUP #</p><ul class='sortable-list'></ul></div>");

        $("div#groups").append(x);
        x.droppable({
            activeClass: 'dragactive',
            hoverClass: 'drophover',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#groups .sortable-list').sortable({
        connectWith: '#groups .sortable-list'
    })

</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable(({
    connectWith: '#groups .sortable-list'
})
</script>

<div class="bootstrap-frm">
    <div>
        <select id="ddlGroups" size="5" runat="server"></select>
    </div>
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="groups">
    </div>

</div>
```

EDIT:

I have amended my code so a new dynamic sortable connected list is created when selecting from the drop down., but I can't drag anything onto the newly created lists.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwnxkme4/30/

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#sortable1, .sortable-list").sortable({
                connectWith: "#sortable2 .sortable-list"
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
                .left {
                    float: left;
                }

                .right {
                    float: right;
                } 
                #center-wrapper {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    width: 920px;
                }               
                .column {
                    margin-left: 2%;
                    width: 400px;
                }

                    .column.first {
                        margin-left: 0;
                    }

                .sortable-list {
                    background-color: #F93;
                    list-style: none;
                    margin: 0;
                    min-height: 60px;
                    padding: 10px;
                }

                .sortable-item {
                    background-color: #FFF;
                    border: 1px solid #000;
                    cursor: move;
                    display: block;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                    padding: 20px 0;
                    text-align: center;
                }            

                #containment {
                    background-color: #FFA;
                    height: 230px;
                }
                .placeholder {
                    background-color: #BFB;
                    border: 1px dashed #666;
                    height: 58px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                }

                #topBar {
                    margin: 40px;
                    height: 50px;
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document.body).on('change', '#multi', function () {
            addSortableDiv($(this).val());
        });

        function addSortableDiv(item) {
            var x = $('<div class="column left" id="' + item + '"><ul class="sortable-list"><li class="sortable-item"></li></ul></div>');
            $("div#sortable2").append(x);
            x.droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {

                }
            });
        };
    </script>


    <div id="dragDropContainer">
        <div id="topBar">
            <select id="multi">
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
                <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
                <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
                <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
                <option value="option10">Option 10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="sortable1" style="width:400px;">

            <div class="column left first">

                <ul class="sortable-list">
                    <li class="sortable-item">Order A</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Order B</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Order C</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Order D</li>
                    <li class="sortable-item">Order E</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sortable2">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: a fiddle would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to adapt this for your needs, i had a look into it as it wasn't something id used before which got me interested and this is what i came up with.

```
$(function(){
    $(".dragMe").draggable(
        {
        revert : function(event, ui) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
                top : 0,
                left : 0
            };
            return (event !== false) ? false : true;
        }
    });
    $("#left, #right").droppable(
        {
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    });

    $("#multi").on("change", function(){
        var item = $(this).val();
        $("#right").append("<p>" + item + "</p>");
    });
});
```

It has the functionality i think your after.

here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eLxd2u8n/2/)
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Parody, but I'd like to create a new droppable div with a sorted list so I can drag and drop from the original list to the newly created ones and back if needs be.